# Backlight won't turn on after suspend on Macbook air (Early 2015)

Tags: 15.10, suspend, brightness, macbook, backlight

After suspending my macbook by closing the lid the backlight will not turn back on however the rest of Ubuntu resumes normally. The screen brightness setting also has no effect on the screen brightness however the keyboard brightness does work fine.

Tested on ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 and its the same.

Comment: Reported bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1550905) will make an answer when its fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by downloading and compiling the [mba6x_bl](https://github.com/patjak/mba6x_bl) driver from github and following the instructions in the readme. Even though this driver is for the macbook air 6 it worked on my air 7,1.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: create /lib/systemd/system-sleep/mba_backlit file (chmod +x) with the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
brt=$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness)
abrt=$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/actual_brightness)
logger -t rc.local "no brightness change needed, brightness is $abrt and actual is $abrt"
if [ "$brt" != "$abrt" ] ; then
echo $abrt > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness
afterbrt=$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness)
logger -t rc.local "changed brightness to $afterbrt and actual brightness is $abrt"
else
afterbrt=$(cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/intel_backlight/brightness)
logger -t rc.local "no brightness change needed, brightness is $afterbrt and actual is $abrt"
fi
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem